# How to display array data after store & email sent?

Tags: laravel-5

UPDATE

I have contact form. it works good. I would like to display $data array at 
 final page which is admintemp.blade.php.

I can display $data array at one step before final page. but I would like to display those at last page too.

I thoguht just add this

```
return view('mail.complete', ['data' => $data]);
```

is fine. but I got this error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Could you teach me right way please?

Here is my code

```
/*
 *confirm page 
 */
public function confirm(Request $request)
{
   $rules = [   
    'orderer' => 'required'
  ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules); 
    $data = $request->all(); 

    $request->session()->put('data',$data);

    return view('mail.confirm', compact("data"));
}


/*
 *　complete page 
 */
public function complete(Request $request)
 { 
   $data = $request->session()->pull('data');
   $token = array_shift($data);
   $Contact = Contact::create($data);      
   $data = session()->regenerateToken();
   return view('mail.complete', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

> UPDATES 2

complete.blade.php

```
@foreach ($data as $val)
{{ $val->id }}
{{ $val->tel }} 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example you have two step form

first step **post** method:

```
public function postCreateStep1(Request $request)
{

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
    ]);

    if (empty($request->session()->get('contact'))) {
        $contact = new Contact();
        $contact->fill($validatedData);
        $request->session()->put('contact', $contact);
    } else {
        $contact = $request->session()->get('contact');
        $contact->fill($validatedData);
        $request->session()->put('contact', $contact);
    }

    return redirect('/create-step2');

}
```

second step **post** method:

```
public function postCreateStep2(Request $request)
{

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'family' => 'required',
    ]);

    if (empty($request->session()->get('contact'))) {
        $contact = new Contact();
        $contact->fill($validatedData);
        $request->session()->put('contact', $contact);
    } else {
        $contact = $request->session()->get('contact');
        $contact->fill($validatedData);
        $request->session()->put('contact', $contact);
    }

    $created_contact = Contact::create([
        'name' => $contact->name,
        'family' => $contact->family,
    ]);
    // Do whatever you want with $created_contact


    return redirect('/');

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate. but it's little difficult for me. when I did error comes up. So Do me a favor could you fix my code please?

Comment: I though more short code. Probabully  my explain was not good. I'm sorry about that. I rewrite question. Could you teach me again please?

Comment: @machagr please read this [article](https://www.5balloons.info/multi-page-step-form-in-laravel-with-validation/) or see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyEOUvCXbkw)..then if you have question I'll answer you

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I read article and watched video. I can display $data array one step before page( confrim page) I can post them and recive them good. So then I would like to display same $data array at final page. I update my question. Could you look it please?

Comment: @machagr please show your mail.complete view...where you use foreach?

Comment: I appreciate that you keep helping me. I update blade file. Could you look at it please?

Comment: @machagr you don't need foreach in your view...get your variable values directly...means: {{ $data->id }} and {{$data->tel}}

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It worked!!! I really appreciate your kindness. Thank you very much again.